# Understanding HashMap#resize function detail

Tags: java, hashmap

The key point of `resize` is recalculating `newCap` and `newThr`. However, in the source code, there are two different ways to calculate `newThr`.

First, when

```
oldCap > DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY && 
oldCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && 
newCap = < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY
```

happens, it uses:

```
// double the old threshold
newThr = oldThr << 1;
```

Second

```
// newCap * load factor
newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Why do we need two different methods? And what does the first condition mean?

Source code of resize function:

```
final Node<K,V>[] resize() {
    Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
    int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
    int oldThr = threshold;
    int newCap, newThr = 0;
    if (oldCap > 0) {
        if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return oldTab;
        }
        else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
                 oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)

            // FIRST!!!
            newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
    }
    else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold
        newCap = oldThr;
    else {               // zero initial threshold signifies using defaults
        newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    // SECOND!!!
    if (newThr == 0) {
        float ft = (float)newCap * loadFactor;
        newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    threshold = newThr;
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
        Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
    table = newTab;
    if (oldTab != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < oldCap; ++j) {
            Node<K,V> e;
            if ((e = oldTab[j]) != null) {
                oldTab[j] = null;
                if (e.next == null)
                    newTab[e.hash & (newCap - 1)] = e;
                else if (e instanceof TreeNode)
                    ((TreeNode<K,V>)e).split(this, newTab, j, oldCap);
                else { // preserve order
                    Node<K,V> loHead = null, loTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> hiHead = null, hiTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> next;
                    do {
                        next = e.next;
                        if ((e.hash & oldCap) == 0) {
                            if (loTail == null)
                                loHead = e;
                            else
                                loTail.next = e;
                            loTail = e;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (hiTail == null)
                                hiHead = e;
                            else
                                hiTail.next = e;
                            hiTail = e;
                        }
                    } while ((e = next) != null);
                    if (loTail != null) {
                        loTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j] = loHead;
                    }
                    if (hiTail != null) {
                        hiTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j + oldCap] = hiHead;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newTab;
}
```

Comment: Because it can only get so big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, if the old threshold was nonzero, the new one is set to twice its size. Otherwise, if the old threshold was zero (whatever that means, not visible in the code excerpt) we need some other way of calculating the new threshold, so we do the second computation. Simple as that?